# Detect an event on jQuery - On change with no click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if any function exist which allows to make the equivalent of the `onChange` event but with no click.

Do you know if that function exists?

For example I have a `<ul>` list which i can click on every `<li>`.

```
<ul>
    <li value="1">val 1</li>
    <li value="2">val 2</li>
    <li value="3">val 3</li>
</ul>
```

And this previous list updates my Select list and selects the new Option

```
<select>
    <option value="1">val 1</option>
    <option value="2">val 2</option>
    <option value="3">val 3</option>
</select>
```

So I must make an event which detects which new value has been selected BUT with no click.

Have you got an idea ? 
Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Why you need another event ?

Comment: Couldn't you do this on the select's change event then if that is the underlying trigger?

Comment: If i click on a LI for example the third which has the value 3 must select the option which has also the value 3. And I only would like to detect the change of that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(yourElement).trigger('change');
```

All this does is fake a change event on your element so if anything is listening for it, it will react accordingly - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's .change() event. This gets called every time the select changed whether its with the keyboard, mouse or other.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "select" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
  });
});
```

Check out the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9s3b48p/)

#### More Information

- [jQuery Documentation - .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the OnChange event on your select simply do after the document loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change();
});
```